# Converting vector of vectors to Matrix in scala

Tags: scala, matrix, vector, scala-breeze

What is the most efficient way to convert `breeze.linalg.Vector[breeze.linalg.Vector[Double]]` to a `DenseMatrix`?

I tried using asDenseMatrix, toBreezeMatrix, creating a new DenseMatrix etc but it seems like I am missing the most simple and obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not real pretty, but this will work and is probably fairly efficient:

```
val v: Vector[Vector[Double]] = ???
val matrix = DenseMatrix(v.valuesIterator.map(_.valuesIterator.toArray).toSeq: _*)
```

You could make this a bit nicer by defining an implicit `LiteralRow` for subclasses of `Vector` like so:

```
implicit def vectorLiteralRow[E, V](implicit ev: V <:< Vector[E]) = new LiteralRow[V, E] {
  def foreach[X](row: V, fn: (Int, E) => X): Unit = row.foreachPair(fn)
  def length(row: V) = row.length
}
```

Now with this implicit in scope you could use

```
val matrix = DenseVector(v.toArray: _*)
```

It seems pretty natural to construct a matrix from its row vectors, so I'm not sure why the breeze library doesn't define implcit `LiteralRows` for subclasses of `Vector`. Maybe someone with more knowledge of the breeze library could comment on this.